# Does Open Source World Need A New Programming Language?

Tags: open-source, programming-languages

Lets look around for famous programming languages and their runtime environments and frameworks...

- C, C++ are hard and complex for a
  small and simple application.
- Java is going to be a commercial
  stuff for Oracle.
- PHP is good but only about web.
- C#, VB.NET and commonly .NET
  Framework is Microsoft product.
- Mono project? A few people trust it
  as i saw!
- Python and ruby and ... They are good
  but not good enough!-

I hope i don't forget any other famous language!

My question is:

**Does Open Source World Need A New Great Programming Language?**

Comment: You mean `Do open source world need a new ...`

Comment: You mean `Does the open source world need a new...`

Comment: I'm sorry for bad english! Yea i mean "Does the open source world need a new..."!

Comment: @Jalal: Check out Scala - the language that has Conciseness of scripting languages, DSL capabilities of Ruby, Sophistication of Haskell, Orthogonality like no other, and runs on the mighty JVM. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question will probably be closed as subjective but here's my subjective view anyway:

**Definitely not**, the open source world is already far too fragmented already and has more than enough languages.

There are already fantastic open source communities around Java, Python, Ruby and PHP. All are great languages for the domains that they are designed for.

There are also some great upcoming languages such as Scala, Clojure etc.

It's a waste of time trying to be perfectionist about what language to use since everyone has a different idea of "perfect" and the value in a language lies in it being well used and providing an open, comprehensive platform for development, not in in being the "perfect" language for just two or three people in the world.